# How to use multithreading in LibGDX?

Tags: android, multithreading, graphics, libgdx

I am making a game in LibGDX. I have a GameScreen(screen) class where the main gameplay happens. I want use use multithreading so that user can do his/her own thing in the screen and computer does its own thing in the screen (changing the output of the screen at the same time). I have good knowledge of multithreading in java. But with graphics i'm confused. Any help will be appereciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. The main thread in libgdx is the GL thread. You can spawn other threads to do stuff in the background, but other threads cannot do anything that involves the GL context, such as loading textures or compiling shaders or drawing anything. Extra threads are rarely needed in mobile games unless you are doing a lot of procedural stuff, maybe. What kind of task are you thinking you need another thread for?

Comment: Currently i'm doing everything in GL thread. Its a card game. When user throws a card, computer starts to play. I have put some time loop to slow the gameplay of computer...but the user cannot move his cards or do anything at that interval. I have put method to call the computer in render after spritebatch ends. I want to use a thread to call the computer so user can do his stuff in main GL thread and computer can do its work in another thread and changing the output of the screen at the same time.

Comment: Ah, OK, makes sense. You basically need the extra threads to call back into `Gdx.app.postRunnable()` when they are done, as they cannot manipulate GL objects (Textures, Sprites, ShaderPrograms, etc). Documentation here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading

Comment: Making new thread only because you need to postpone computer reaction is not worth. You can count a time in game loop, and let the computer does it's job just after the counter reaches, eg. 1000ms from player's turn ends. (commenting after months because I really don't like @Tenfour04's "OK, makes sense")

Comment: @Reloecc maybe I misunderstood the OP. I thought they were doing long running algorithms to determine the computer's move while continuing to run animations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use threading as per usual. Only thing you have to think of is that just as when working with swing only the graphics thread can do graphics operations so if your worker thread needs anything from graphics use the libgdx PostRunnable command.

Answer (score 1):

Rather late but let me clarify something if I can.
Generally on LibGDX you have to be careful with threading.
Having said that, and if you decide you are not interested in html, you could start a thread normally and when you need to change something in the UI you should use Gdx.app.postRunnable() method

For code example and limitations, have a look here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading

Answer (score 0):

As per the page https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading , if you're hoping to create an HTML5 version of your game, then you won't be able to use traditional threads:-

> JavaScript is inherently single-threaded. As such, threading is
>   impossible.